# using string to break out of loop in java

Tags: java, string, integer

I simply would like to break out of a `while true` loop if the user enters in "STOP" into the scanner. Currently my scanner only takes in integers and I believe this is where the problem lies. If I try to type in "STOP" I get many errors saying "exception in thread main". Here is a snippet of my code:

```
public class algorithm {
private Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int n;

while (true){
    System.out.println("Eneter a number to check if it is odd or even, then hit enter: ");
    System.out.println("Type 'STOP' to end the program");
    n = input.nextInt();

    String strN = String.valueOf(n); //convert integer to string
    if (new String(strN).equals("STOP")){ //if string is STOP, breaks
        System.out.println("Thanks for using my program");
        break;
    }

    if (n % 2 == 0){
        System.out.println(n+" is even");
        continue;
    }
    else{
        System.out.println(n+" is odd");
        continue;
```

I know I am missing some closing curly braces but rest assured they are all there in my actual code. Thanks.

Here is the error I am getting:
`Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at OddOrEven.algorithm.checker(algorithm.java:13)
    at OddOrEven.main.main(main.java:7)`

Comment: `.nextInt()`? you need to prompt for a string, then, not an int.

Comment: I don't think `nextInt()` will check if a user enters "stop".

Comment: Yes, I tried this already. But wouldnt I have to convert the strings into integers to check if they're odd or even?

Comment: What is the exception type?

Comment: Prompt for a string, then check whether that string is "STOP" or try to cast it to int otherwise.

Comment: Why do you do this: `new String(strN)` if `strN` is a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've already identified the problem yourself - your Scanner reads only integers:

```
int n;
...
n = input.nextInt();
```

so it's impossible for the variable `n` (an int) to contain the string "STOP" (and your Scanner throws an exception anyway when you call `nextInt()` but it encounters a string, such as "STOP", that it cannot convert to an int).

To do this, you need to read strings from the input (probably using `Scanner.nextLine()`), check whether they are "STOP", and if not, only then attempt to convert them to ints using something like:

```
int n = Integer.parseInt(mystring)
```

To handle garbage input (neither STOP nor an integer), wrap the `parseInt` line in a `try-catch` block so that you can detect when the input is garbage by catching the [Exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)

```
try {
  int i = Integer.parseInt(mystring);
  // do something with the int
}
catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  // display warning message to the user instead
}
```

See also this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456219/java-checking-if-parseint-throws-exception).

Comment: How could I check if the user typed in a garbage string, such as "dsfasdfsa" and then print out something like "Please enter a valid input"? Cause at the moment, I am doing exactly what you did, if the user didnt type in STOP, i cast it to a string. But I get many errors if I type in a garbage string.

Comment: Wrap the `parseInt` line in a `try-catch` block so that you can detect when the input is garbage by catching the [Exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)

Comment: Hey, I actually created a separate method that contained a try-catch block, Worked great. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The most simple way is probably to use input.next() instead of input.nextInt().  Using input.next() will read input in as a String, then you can check if the input is equal to "QUIT", if it is not you can use Integer.parseInt to parse the Integer from the read string

Answer (score 1):

Something like below, should work out.

NOTE: havent tested compile errors, just wrote it out(but you get a gist)

```
     public Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n;

while (true){
    System.out.println("Eneter a number to check if it is odd or even, then hit enter: ");
    System.out.println("Type 'STOP' to end the program");
    n = input.next();
    Integer input;

   // String strN = String.valueOf(n); //convert integer to string
    if (strN.equals("STOP")){ //if string is STOP, breaks
        System.out.println("Thanks for using my program");
        break;
    }
    else{
        try{
    input=  Integer.parseInt(strN);

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter a  number");
        }
    }

    if (input % 2 == 0){
        System.out.println(n+" is even");
        continue;
    }
    else{
        System.out.println(n+" is odd");
        continue;
    }
```