# Detecting the user input as an error for string input in java

Tags: java, string, conditional-statements

What can I do to detect string input as an error, where the user has to enter an int value?
What is the condition I can use to detect whether the user has entered a string value?

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
int characterNum = input.nextInt();

do{

 if ((characterNum < 0)&&(characterNum > 12)){
 System.out.println("Invalid Input, Try again");

  }

 characterNum = input.nextInt();

 }while((characterNum < 0)&&(characterNum > 12));
```

Comment: What I understood is, you are trying to get user input but you want to make sure it is a numeric value?

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456219/java-checking-if-parseint-throws-exception

Comment: can you put your code to see how are you trying to do ??

Comment: @ElSheikh yes exactly

Comment: @S.Liyanage check David's comment

Comment: @abby37 This is the part(loop) which i used to validate the range of the input number. How can I add the string validation condition in the same loop?

Comment: [nextInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) from the docs, it won't accept the string and it will throw input mismatch exception. So why you want to put additional condition for string or I may be missing something in question ??

Answer (score -2):

By Using instanceof :

Use "s instanceof String" , where s is variable entered by user to check wither it is String or not

Comment: If the OP takes a string as input, and they want to know if it is or is not parsable as an integer, `instanceof String` is obviously going to be true. If they try and take input as something other than a string, it will be false. Either way, it is not helpful.